# A problem of triangles.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

**Question**: "In triangle $ABC$, angle $B$ measures $68°$ degrees and angle $C$ is $40°$ degrees. $AD$ and $BE$ are heights, $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and $N$ is the midpoint of $AC$.Calcule angles $DNM$ and $EDN$."
$$$$Therefore the angle $ A $ measures $ 72 ° $, and making a drawing here in geogebra, thought $DNM=28°$ and $EDN=32°$, **How to find this with calculations?**

Comment: AD and BE are "high"?

Comment: @dotslash: Heights (an angle $90°$ with the base of picking up the thread vertex side)

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: "altitudes" is the word.

Answer (score 1):

$$\angle DNM=\angle DNC - \angle MNC\\=180^\circ-2\angle ACB-\angle BAC\\=180^\circ-2\times 40^\circ-72^\circ=28^\circ.$$
$$\angle EDN=\angle EDC -\angle NDC\\=\angle BAC - \angle ACB\\=72^\circ-40^\circ=32^\circ.$$

Comment: in the case $DN=NC$?

Comment: No. I only used the facts that 1) $MN\parallel AB$, 2) $DE$ and $AB$ are [antiparallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparallel_%28mathematics%29) with respect to $CA$ and $CB$, and 3) in right triangles the median corresponding to hypotenuse cuts the triangle into two isosceles triangles.

Comment: :Could more detail?
I'm not including the resolution

Comment: :Did not understand the second part. The first I got.

Comment: Note that $\Delta EDC$ and $\Delta ABC$ are similar with $\angle EDC = \angle BAC$. Furthermore, $\Delta NDC$ is isosceles ($ND = NC = NA$). So $\angle NDC = \angle ACB$.

Comment: Because $\Delta EDC$ and $\Delta ABC$ are similar?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior Which part are you referring to? 1) The right triangles $\Delta CDA$ and $\Delta CEB$ are similar, which implies the similarity of the other two triangles I mentioned. 2) $\Delta NDC$ is isosceles because $AC$ is the hypthenuse of the right triangle $\Delta ACD$ and $DN$ is its corresponding median.

Comment: I do not understand why that $\Delta EDC$ and $\Delta ABC$ are similar ..

Comment: @marcelolpjunior How do you prove two triangles are similar? Try to use what I said in 1) in my previous comment.